# Looking for an algorithm to a unique problem

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, algebra

I have six arrays that are each given a (not necessarily unique) value from one to fifty. I am also given a number of items to split between them. The value of each item is defined by the array it is in. Arrays can hold infinite or zero items, but the sum of items in all arrays must equal the original number of items given.

I want to find the best configuration of items in arrays where the sum of item values in each individual array are as close as possible to each other.

For instance, let's say that I have three arrays with a value of 10 and three arrays with a value of 20. For nine items, one would go in each of the '20' arrays and two would go into each of the '10' arrays so that the sum of each array is 20 and the total number of items is nine.

I can't add a fractional number of items to an array, and the numbers are hardly ever perfectly divisible like that example, but there always exists a solution where the difference between the sums is minimal.

I'm currently using brute force to solve this problem, but performance suffers with larger numbers of items. I feel like there is a mathematical answer to this problem, but I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Comment: By minimal difference between sums you mean the maximum difference between any 2 arrays or sum of differences for all pairs of arrays, or it is something else?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to write a greedy algorithm that comes up with an approximate solution. Just always add the next item to the array with the lowest sum of values.

The array with the highest value should be within 1 item of being correct.

For each count of items in the array with the highest value, you can repeat the exercise.  Getting the array with the second highest value to within 1.

Continue through all of them, and with 6 arrays you'll wind up with `3^5 = 243` possible arrangements of items (note that the number of items in the last array is entirely determined by the first 5).  Pick the best of these and your combinatorial explosion is contained.

(This approach should work if you're trying to minimize the value difference between the largest and smallest array, and have a fixed number of arrays.  )